# Proof by induction that for every positive integer there is a multiple $m$ for which the digit sum $D(m)=D(m^2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I am an early university student in a math related field and want to practice proofs. In this context I have found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4158701/if-da-is-the-digit-sum-of-a-is-there-a-positive-multiple-m-for-every-po) post ("If $D(a)$ is the digit sum of $a$, is there a positive multiple $m$ for every positive integer $n$, such that $D(m)=D(m^2)$") a few hours ago. As I found the proposition interesting I tried to prove this statement.

My plan was to proof it by induction:

- It is of course true for $a=1$, as $m=1\cdot 1=1$ and such $D(m)=D(1)=D(m^2)=D(1)=1$
- Next I assume that the statement hold for all $a$, if it also holds for $a+1$
- The last step would be to show it for $a+1$ to prove it for $a$:

So we have $m=(a+1)\cdot b=ab+b, b\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m^2=(a+1)^2\cdot b^2=(a^2+2a+1)\cdot b^2=a^2b^2+2ab^2+b^2$. That must mean that $D(ab+b)=D(a^2b^2+2ab^2+b^2)$ for all $a\in\mathbb{N}$ with some arbitrary $b\in\mathbb{N}$.

This is also the part where I fail to make any meaningful progress because I  don't find out when this equality holds even after trying for longer than I probably should have.

Because of this I want to ask how I could proceed here, tips should suffice because in the end I want to learn something. Or maybe this idea of proving it by induction is totally off the track...

Comment: If you assume it's true for all $a$, then you've assumed the statement is true.  You would need to assume it for some $a$, though I don't see how this could be proved by induction, even if it's true.

Comment: Sorry, I got my induction 101 mixed up. I'll correct it...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. But that is not true for all $n\equiv 0$ or $1\mod 9$, like when $n=27$, so that would not suffice (I think?).

Answer (score 2):

First case:$gcd(n,10)=1$ put $m=10^k-1$ it's obvios that $D(m)=D(m^2)$ also since $gcd(n,10)=1$ there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $n|10^k-1$ now for a positive integer $n$ such that gcd(n,10)=1 define $f(n)$ as the smallest multiple of $n$ such that $D(f(n)^2)=D(f(n)$
Second case: let $n=2^a×3^b×t$ such that $gcd(t,10)=1$ now put $m=10^(max(m,n)) × f(t)$ it's obvios that $n|m$ also $D(m^2)=1+D(f(t)^2)$ also $D(m)=1+D(f(t))$ by definition of $f$ we are done!